# Multiple series data on HighCharts column

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts on a project, and I'm having trouble formatting the data in the way I'd like.  I currently have something that works, but it doesn't feel quite right.

What I have is a column chart with everything in one series.  I'd rather have each data point be in it's own series & properly labeled in the legend & tooltips.  Below are samples of the relevant bits to format the data.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the changes I've made feel like they should work given their [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) & [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic).  Also, Do I need the categories if multiple series works?

### Working:

```
"series": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "y": 92,
          "name": "Apples: 92ms for 83,481,430 requests",
          "color": "#91cb73"
        },
        {
          "y": 761,
          "name": "Bananas: 761ms for 58,050,877 requests",
          "color": "#ab7053"
        },
        {
          "y": 774,
          "name": "Kiwis: 774ms for 362,294 requests",
          "color": "#44719c"
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b65kp/

---

### Not working:

```
 "series": [
    {
      "name": "Apples",
      "data": {
        "y": 92,
        "name": "92ms for 83,481,430 requests",
        "color": "#91cb73"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Bananas",
      "data": {
        "y": 761,
        "name": "761ms for 58,050,877 requests",
        "color": "#ab7053"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Kiwis",
      "data": {
        "y": 774,
        "name": "774ms for 362,294 requests",
        "color": "#44719c"
      }
    }
]
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u74Qw/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `"data"` expects an array, and you are giving it an object. Wrap each object in an array. For example:

```
"data": [{
        "y": 92,
        "name": "92ms for 83,481,430 requests",
        "color": "#91cb73"
 }]
```

[Here is your full fix](http://jsfiddle.net/GzjqN/1/), but it might not give the result you expect, personally I like your first attempt better

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - thank you! Hmm, you are right though, this doesn't actually do what I thought it would.  I suppose I'll stick with my first attempt, hide the legend, and use a tooltip formatter to get that showing up as I want.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, alternate approach to `setting this up`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/zbW4D/

Things to consider:

1) using a legend instead of just directly labeling each bar makes the user do a lot of looking back and forth to see which is which  (doing both just adds extra clutter to distract the user)

2) rotating labels always adds more work for the user

3) multiple colors for the bars is not necessary when each bar is labeled appropriately, and again just adds distraction

A horizontal bar chart with no legend and single color for data solves these problems.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks.  These all make a lot of sense.  Right now I am upgrading an application from flash charts to HighCharts, so priority 1 is making them look like they did before.  I may go back through these later and make these changes you suggested when I'm done.

Comment: Hmm, although I do display some similar data in a pie chart as well, so having the different colors really helps out there & it might look strange to have each item color-coded in the bar graph and not in the pie graph.

Comment: Well, the solution there is to not use a pie chart :)  There is plenty of good reading material around that points to bar charts being a far superior method of showing pretty much any data that people commonly put into pie charts, despite pie charts being the choice most of us are taught.  For example:  http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf